# PIC18F array allocation

Tags: arrays, string, memory, pic, xc8

I have a array of struct with a const char* element and a char* element. I change the char* element value with memcpy then i call a function where i declare a char array and thats all. Depending on the size of this array the char* element value change between NULL and the correct value. I attached two picture, depict the problem. Thank you for reply

PIC18F26k83
MPLAB X IDE 5.50
XC8 v2.32

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmfq6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqThY.png)

```
item items[] = {
    {"front", ""}, {"back", ""}};

size_t num_items = sizeof(items) / sizeof(item);

item* linearSearch(item* items, size_t size,const char* key) {
for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if (strcmp(items[i].key, key) == 0) {
        return &items[i];
    }
}
return NULL;
}

void checkState(const char *key,const char *newState)
{
item* found = linearSearch(items, num_items, key);

result = strncmp(found->value, newState, strlen(newState));
if(result == 0)
{
    uart_putString("not changed\r\n");
}
else
{
   found->value =  num_items;
   exresult = executeCommand(key, newState);
   if(exresult)
   {
        memcpy(found->value, newState, strlen(newState)+1);
       // uart_putString(response);
        //__delay_ms(500);
      successful();
       uart_putString("changed\r\n");    
   }
   else
   {
       //unsuccessful(key, newState);
       uart_putString("error\r\n");
   }
     
}   
memset(rxbuffer, 0, sizeof rxbuffer);
memset(command_list, 0, sizeof command_list);    
// memset(response, 0, sizeof response);
}
void successful()
{

char valami[19] ="valami" ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dani, you have not mentioned what the problem is. Please explain your problem clearly and straight forward in order to provide you a solution. I did not see the problem from the pictures. I only see that the `value` pointer is null at first, and in second it points to somewhere in the memory.

Comment: In checkState, before you do the strncmp, check that found isn't NULL.  If found is NULL then found->value is undefined.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for reply. The problem was when i declared 19 or higher elements array in sucessful function. This overwrite the found->value memory are. In meantime it has been solved, this line
"found->value =  num_items;" was the problem, here i add new memory area to the pointer, after successful function overwrite this area. In shortly bad pointer usage was the problem.

Comment: You can post your answer to your question, wait a bit and then mark it as the answer.